# nodemon stuck on "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..." on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

please help me here, I am facing this problem and CAN'T figure out.
After I run docker compose-up, nodemon start to monitoring normally, after changes, it gets stuck in `[nodemon] restarting due to changes...` and nothing else happens after that.

What I tried so far was:

- Use `--legacy` flag
- Reset and Reinstall Docker
- Use an older/newer version of Node and Nodemon
- Set Docker to run as Administrator and give firewall permissions.

I just can't find where is the problem.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/twa

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .
```

Here's the Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    node:
        container_name: node
        build: .
        user: node
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes: 
            - ".:/usr/src/twa"
        command: "npm run dev"
```

Here's package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "api_twa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": ,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --watch src src/server.js"
  },
  "author": ,
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "tedious": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
  }
}
```

Here's the app file:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')

require('./database')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(routes)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
```

I am using Docker version 19.03.8

Windows 10 Pro (fresh installed)
Version 1909
Installed on 29/04/2020
OS build 18363.815

If I try to restart the container, it doesn't do anything.

Here's the log with `--verbose`

```
> api_twa@1.0.0 dev /usr/src/twa

> nodemon --verbose --watch src src/server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.3

[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`

[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 24 to restart

[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*

[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`

[nodemon] forking

[nodemon] child pid: 37

[nodemon] watching 7 files

Server running on port 3000

[nodemon] files triggering change check: src/controllers/UserController.js

[nodemon] matched rule: /usr/src/twa/src/**/*

[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] src/controllers/UserController.js

[nodemon] child pid: 47
```

If anyone PLEASE help me here, I'm stuck with this...

Comment: Can you use `nodemon --verbose` to get more details about what's happening

Comment: @MickaelB. I just edited the question with logs.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had faces same issue on "NODEMON",
And now i have a solution on Nodemon stuck on [NODEMON] restarting due to change....

Follow this steps..

1.go to this path..

**C/windows/system32**.

Copy this math and follow below steps..

```
Open **THIS PC**

On right click : **properties**
```

Then go to : **Advance System Settings**

Next click on : **Environment Variables..**

Next : user variable for admin in this

**Double Click on *PATH***

Next : **New**

And **paste** that copied path here.

And click on next all **OK**..

Enjoy Your NODEMON is on the Job ...